# How do you test a Jersey Web Service with Spring using the Jersey Test Framework

Tags: web-services, jersey, integration-testing, glassfish-3

I am trying to test my web service using the Jersey Test Framework but what test container factory do you use to test Spring web services? I tried the EmbeddedGlassfishContainerFactory but it keeps looking for a sun-web.xml file but I am using the newest version of the Glassfish file called glassfish-web.xml. Using the GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory it gave me an error regarding EJB invocation. I tried to find a good example of someone using Spring with the Jersey Test Framework but I could not find any that works.

Comment: Just FYI, under typical definitions (I don't think this is a settled issue) this would not be a unit test because unit tests only test the code you have direct control over.  Since you're using libraries and an app server, this is more of an integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by following what this guy did:
http://ameethpaatil.blogspot.ca/2011/09/restful-webservice-jersey-spring-30x.html